# Registering multiple phrases for one specific task using Siri Shortcuts

Tags: ios, sirikit, sirishortcuts

Is there a way to register multiple phrases to SiriKit for one specific action?

For example, Siri should Book the table through my app when the user says "Book a table for 2 at ABC hotel" or "Reserve a table for 2 at ABC hotel"

I tried registering multiple shortcuts for one action (with Donated Shortcuts), however, it shows only one shortcut in Settings->Siri & Search.